# How do I manipulate a binary plist retrieved using urllib2.urlopen into a readable xml plist without saving the file locally using Python?

Tags: python

We use a Python script to communicate with our Deploy Studio server to automate the updating of user and computer information using Deploy Studio's web access URLs. Due to a recent change, they are now storing the Plists for computers in the binary plist format as opposed to XML.

Here is what currently works with old version of DS (source: http://macops.ca/interfacing-with-deploystudio-using-http/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib2
import plistlib
from random import randrange

host = 'https://my.ds.repo:60443'
adminuser = 'testdsuser'
adminpass = '12345'


def setupAuth():
    """Install an HTTP Basic Authorization header globally so it's used for
every request."""
    auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password(realm='DeployStudioServer',
                              uri=host,
                              user=adminuser,
                              passwd=adminpass)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)


def getHostData(machine_id):
    """Return the full plist for a computer entry"""
    machine_data = urllib2.urlopen(host + '/computers/get/entry?id=%s' % machine_id)
    plist = plistlib.readPlistFromString(machine_data.read())
    # if id isn't found, result will be an empty plist
    return plist


def updateHostProperties(machine_id, properties, key_mac_addr=False, create_new=False):
    """Update the computer at machine_id with properties, a dict of properties and
values we want to set with new values. Return the full addinfourl object or None
if we found no computer to update and we aren't creating a new one. Set create_new
to True in order to enable creating new entries."""
    found_comp = getHostData(machine_id)

    # If we found no computer and we don't want a new record created
    if not found_comp and not create_new:
        return None

    new_data = {}
    if found_comp:
        # Computer data comes back as plist nested like: {'SERIALNO': {'cn': 'my-name'}}
        # DeployStudioServer expects a /set/entry POST like: {'cn': 'my-new-name'}
        # so we copy the keys up a level
        update = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in found_comp[machine_id].items())
        new_data = update.copy()
    else:
        # No computer exists for this ID, we need to set up two required keys:
        # 'dstudio-host-primary-key' and one of 'dstudio-host-serial-number'
        # or 'dstudio-mac-addr' is required, otherwise request is ignored
        # - IOW: you can't only rely on status codes
        # - primary key is a server-level config, but we seem to need this per-host
        if key_mac_addr:
            new_data['dstudio-host-primary-key'] = 'dstudio-mac-addr'
        else:
            new_data['dstudio-host-primary-key'] = 'dstudio-host-serial-number'
        new_data[new_data['dstudio-host-primary-key']] = machine_id

    for (k, v) in properties.items():
        new_data[k] = v
    plist_to_post = plistlib.writePlistToString(new_data)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(host + '/computers/set/entry?id=' + machine_id,
                            plist_to_post)
    return result


def main():
    setupAuth()

    # Update HOWSANNIE with a new computer name (assuming this entry already exists)
    random_name = 'random-id-' + str(randrange(100))
    result = updateHostProperties('HOWSANNIE', {'cn': random_name,
                                            'dstudio-hostname': random_name})

    # Update DOUGLASFIRS with a new computername and custom properties, or create
    # it if it doesn't already exist
    random_name = 'random-id-' + str(randrange(100))
    updateHostProperties('DOUGLASFIRS',
                    {'cn': random_name,
                    'dstudio-hostname': random_name,
                    'dstudio-custom-properties': [{
                        'dstudio-custom-property-key': 'ASSET_TAG',
                        'dstudio-custom-property-label': 'My Great Asset Tag',
                        'dstudio-custom-property-value': 'BL4CKL0DG3'}]
                    },
                    create_new=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

We use this in conjunction with a home-grown web interface for our technicians to enter in the information when re-imaging a machine and automatically update the information in our DS database.

I've tried using libraries such as [biplist](https://github.com/wooster/biplist) to no avail. I'd prefer to not have to store the file locally on the server and then convert it using the bash command [plutil](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/plutil.1.html). Is there anyway I can manipulate the variable the information gets stored into? In this case it would be 'machine_data'.

I've had success using the bash command curl with the -o flag to indicate saving the file as a .plist file which works, however as said before, I would like to do this without saving the file locally if possible.

Deploy Studio web services available: [image: here].

Comment: Is it possible to take the variable in the above example, machine_data, and use the new load function or does that only work on a physical file hence forcing me to store the binary data locally first? That's what I am trying to avoid if I don't have to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a go this afternoon and see if I can get it functioning properly.

Comment: if you find you can't find a way to do this without using a disk, you could always you a [ramdisk](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-create-linux-ram-disk-filesystem/) to do it.

Comment: So why exactly does `biplist.readPlistFromString()` not work for you?

Comment: Note that both `biplist.readPlistFromString()` and `plistlib.loads()` *simply create a `io.BytesIO` in-memory file object* to wrap the data. Any library that only takes a file object could be adapted to take in-memory data the same way.

Comment: xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 9

Line throwing the error: plist = plistlib.readPlistFromString(machine_data.read())

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment was not using biplist. I'll post those results shortly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Using `plist = readPlist(machine_data)` here is the results: AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: @BcnDoge: Yes, but you can use a `io.BytesIO()` object still. The return value from `urllib` is not a seekable file-like object, but `io.BytesIO()` *is*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So how do I adapt the code to utilize `io.BytesIO()`? I guess I'm not fully understanding how to still grab the data using `urllib` portion then read it using `io.BytesIO()`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @BcnDoge: `BytesIO(response.read())`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Got it to not error out anymore, which is progress. Printing out the results of the `BytesIO(response.read())` I get: `<_io.BytesIO object at 0x109d88650>`.

If I try printing out the variable with `.getvalue()`, it DOES print out information within the XML, however it is incorrectly formatted. Example: `bplist00?wYcomputersVgroups??


!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCQ^kx??????????!.;HUbo|??????????
                                                                   %2?LYfs??????????)` There are correct serial numbers and other info that does print correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting together all of @martijn-pieters comments into an answer:

`pip install biplist`

```
import urllib2
import io
import biplist

sock = urllib2.urlopen('https://cfpropertylist.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/sample.binary.plist' )
buf = io.BytesIO(sock.read())
xml = biplist.readPlist(buf)
print xml
```

Output:

> {'Pets Names': [], 'Name': 'John Doe', 'Picture': '<B\x81\xa5\x81\xa5\x99\x81B<', 'Year Of Birth': 1965, 'Date Of Graduation': datetime.datetime(2004, 6, 22, 19, 23, 43), 'City Of Birth': 'Springfield', 'Kids Names': ['John', 'Kyra']}

Comment: Thanks! This does answer the question and allow me to manipulate the data. I do however need to work out exactly how to search for a specific record, update parts of the data, then resubmit the data back in a the correct formatting for the DS database to read it.

Comment: You can have a look at python implementations of JSONPath for advanced searching on JSON constructs, or just manipulation on dict objects after parsing it. You can always post more follow up questions (after you tried stuff and it didn't work!) :)